# Xamarin.Forms: IValueConverter only works once

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to control the background color of a label by changing the color of the selected label. I am following the MVVM pattern, and the way I have implemented is like:

1. In the Model I have created a boolean, with get and set, which has to detect if an item in my listview is selected. `public boolean Selected {get; set;}`
2. In my view, I bind the background color property to the boolean, and set the IValueConverter as the Converter
3. In the ViewModel, I implement the get and set

It seems that it only checks once, as the background color is always white. I have checked it with breakpoints in the Converter, and it only gets called when the list is initiated, but not when the items are updated.

IValueConverter:

```
public class SelectedItemColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter implementation

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                if ((Boolean)value)
                    return Color.Red;
                else
                    return Color.White;
            }
            return Color.White;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the ListView:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="standingsStackLayout" IsVisible="False">
                <ListView x:Name="standingsList" SeparatorColor="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding StandingsListSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label x:Name="TournamentNameLabel" Text="{Binding TournamentName}" 
                                       TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                       BackgroundColor="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}"/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel code:

```
public HistoricalStandingsData _selectedItem;
    public HistoricalStandingsData SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            { 
                if(_selectedItem != null)
                    _selectedItem.Selected = false;

                _selectedItem = value;

                if (_selectedItem != null)
                    _selectedItem.Selected = true;


                TournamentLabelName = _selectedItem.TournamentName;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
                //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_selectedItem.Selected));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added the     `<ContentPage.Resources>` for the Converter

Comment: Selection tracking for Collections is usually done via a CollectionView. See point 8 in that old MVVM intro I wrote: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: I'd assume your data source needs to implement ‘INotifyPropertyChanged‘ in order to notify the burbs on property updates.

Comment: @orhtej2 : Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work :(

Comment: @Hudhud thing is that what you did only updates binding source to the ListView as a whole, what you need to do is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on individual properties of `HistoricalStandingsData` as that's what your converter is bound to.

Comment: You should use a baseViewModel which implements [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) for all your viewModels, cause [orthej2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7034621/orhtej2) is right. And it's the easiest way to use a baseViewModel :)

Comment: @orhtej2 I have also tried with `_selectedItem.Selected`.

Comment: @Hudhud but it's `HistoricalStandingsData` that meant to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the binding is unaware of the parent class that holds the reference.

Comment: @orhtej2: I honestly can't see what's wrong. You mean that I have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at your View

```
<StackLayout x:Name="standingsStackLayout" IsVisible="False">
    <ListView x:Name="standingsList" SeparatorColor="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding StandingsListSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label x:Name="TournamentNameLabel" Text="{Binding TournamentName}" 
                           TextColor="{StaticResource textColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           BackgroundColor="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

We can see there are two major data bindings happening here. First, `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` property is bound to `StandingsListSource` property of your view model. Two things can change this: Either the object pointed to by `StandingsListSource` as a whole or the collections contents.

The official documentation on bindings has the [following to say regarding binding `ListView.ItemsSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/):

> The `ListView` is quite sophisticated in handling changes that might
>   dynamically occur in the underlying data, but only if take certain
>   steps. If the collection of items assigned to the `ItemsSource` property
>   of the `ListView` changes during runtime—that is, if items can be added
>   to or removed from the collection—use an `ObservableCollection` class
>   for these items. `ObservableCollection` implements the
>   `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, and `ListView` will install a
>   handler for the `CollectionChanged` event.

Let's do just that (full implementation of `DataSource` class I use as a `BindingContext` for the form later):

```
public ObservableCollection<HistoricalStandingsData> StandingsListSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<HistoricalStandingsData>();
```

For simplicity I made `StandingsListSource` a [C# 6.0 readonly auto property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917886/7034621) to eliminate the need of tracking it's reassignment.

Now, since `ListView.SelectedItem` is bound as well we need some way to notify `ListView` that selected item was updated from code behind. Enter the second advice from documentation mentioned before:

> If properties of the items themselves change during runtime, then the
>   items in the collection should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`
>   interface and signal changes to property values using the
>   `PropertyChanged` event.

This has 2 implications:

- `HistoricalStandingsData` should notify when it's properties change because each row in `ListView` binds to this property as per `DataTemplate`:

  ```
  public class HistoricalStandingsData : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public HistoricalStandingsData(string name)
      {
          this.TournamentName = name;
      }

      private bool selected;

      public bool Selected
      {
          get
          {
              return selected;
          }

          set
          {
              selected = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Selected)));
          }
      }

      public string TournamentName { get; }

      // From INotifyPropertyChanged
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
  ```
- View model class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify on properties, in this case `SelectedItem` changes.

  ```
  class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public ObservableCollection<HistoricalStandingsData> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<HistoricalStandingsData>();

      public HistoricalStandingsData SelectedItem
      {
          // Information on selection is stored in items themselves, use Linq to find the single matching item
          get => Items.Where(x => x.Selected).SingleOrDefault();
          set
          {
              // Reset previous selection
              var item = SelectedItem;
              if (item != null)
                  item.Selected = false;

              // Mark new item as selected, raising HistoricalStandingItem.PropertyChanged
              if (value != null)
                  value.Selected = true;

              // Notify observers that SelectedItem changed
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
          }
      }

      // From INotifyPropertyChanged
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public DataSource()
      {
          // Helper ICommand used for appending new items to HistoricalStandingsData
          AddNew = new Command(() =>
          {
              var item2 = new HistoricalStandingsData(DateTime.Now.ToString());
              // Append, notifies observers that collection has changed.
              Items.Add(item2);
              // Set as selected, resetting previous selection
              SelectedItem = item2;
          });
      }

      public ICommand AddNew { get; } 
  }
  ```

`AddNew` command is optional, I added it for testing purposes.