# How to use const in C# class constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, constants

Let's say I have a class like this:

```cs
public class SampleClass
{
    const string UnChangableUserName { get; private set; }
    string Password { get; private set; }

    public SampleClass(string UnChangableUserName, string Password)
    {
        this.Password = Password;
        this.UnChangableUserName = UnChangableUserName;
    }
}
```

I want the constructor to assign a value to the const, and not for the value to be set when the const is defined. How can I do it?

I'm aware I can simply not use set but using const is more resource efficent and more elegant as well as clearer to other devs to understand, I don't want a set so they will not add it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't. By definition, `const`s in C# are defined at *compile-time*, not at runtime. They can't be changed by any code, even constructor code, because they're not even *there* at runtime - they're replaced by their literal values at every point of usage.

What you're looking for is either `readonly fields` or `read only properties`.

1. Readonly fields are marked by the `readonly` modifier:

   `private readonly string _username;`

   Readonly fields are only assignable during construction, either directly assigned in the definition itself (`readonly string _username = "blah"`) or in the constructor. The compiler will enforce this limitation, and will not allow you to set a value anywhere else.
2. Readonly properties are simply properties that don't expose a setter at all. Until C# 6, you could use them to return the value of a readonly field (as above), but you couldn't assign to them. As of C# 6, though, there's syntax supporting read-only auto-properties that can be assigned: even though there's no explicit setter, there's an implicit setter that can, again, only be called from the constructor, or from a field initializer:

   `public string Username { get } = "Username"`;

   It may look strange that you're setting to a property with no setter, but that's simply an implicit part of the language - there's an implicit backing field that's `readonly`, and can be set at initialization.

Comment: Readonly properties supported from C# 1... Newer versions bring different syntax to express that so...

Comment: Technically, pre-C# 6 properties can be read-only, but not *assignable* - you can't have assignable read-only auto-properties. You can have properties with getters that return a read-only field, that's true, but you'll have to do the assignment separately.

Answer (score 1):

a const is a CONSTANT at compilation. You need a readonly property.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917886/910741