# When would I want to use fields instead of auto-implemented properties?

Tags: c#

Is there any situation where creating a field (apart from readonly, [but only because language designers haven't implemented it for properties yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166744/why-cant-properties-be-readonly)), are there situations where fields have any advantages over properties?

Comment: Respectfully, I don't agree that it's a duplicate. In context of this question, I understand the difference, and understand the numerous advantages of properties. However, after reading a lot of property/field debate, I came to idea that I must be missing something good about fields, and asked about this specific detail. Not the whole comparison.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should remember that a Property, in .NET, is nothing more than just a syntactic sugar for 2 methods - one method for the property get section, and one for the property set section.

If you talk about **public fields vs properties** than the answer is: it is always better to use properties than public fields. Why? Because you achieve encapsulation which makes your code much more maintainable in the future.

If you talk about **private fields vs properties** than I would say: it is better to use private fields, because  there is no reason to use properties in this case.
There might be some exceptions though like for lazy loading:

```
private string _someField;
private string SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (_someField== null)
        {
            _someField= LoadData();
        }

        return _someField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily public, no.

Comment: Wouldn't a property of Lazy<T> be a better choice for lazy loading?

Comment: Yes, it would be obviously a better choice assuming that you work with .Net 4.5+

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use fields for private and usually protected members, to make it explicit that this is just the state of the object and avoid the notational clutter.

I use properties for public members (and protected in big hierarchies), to get the typical benefits, like that I can change the behaviour later if I want to, have it on the interface, mock it later, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues provided a good case when fields are more convenient:

```
float m_Time = 0;
```

Simple initialization of default values.

Comment: But you can do the same with properties, just in this case you won't use the auto-implemented ones.