# Why can't readonly be used with properties

Tags: c#

Why properties in C# cannot be readonly ?

When I try to have a property readonly it states that:

> a modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item

Simmilar question was asked here:
[Why can't properties be readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166744/why-cant-properties-be-readonly)
But the question was asked 5 years ago, and the answer provided then was: Because they didn't think it thru. Is this still the case after 5 years?

edit:
Code example:

```
public class GreetingClass
{
    public readonly string HelloText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you please post your code

Comment: Well, technically nothing changed after that 5 years, and all answers to question you've mentioned are still up to date.

Comment: Well, *property* is just a convenient name for `get`/`set` accessors which a *methods*.

Comment: See my answer. It compares C# 6.0 and prior versions. Things have changed a bit in C# 6.0.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Properties can be readonly in C#, the implementation is just not using the readonly keyword:

If you use C#6 (VS 2015) you can use the following line, which allows assigning the property in either the constructor or in the member definition.

```
public int Property { get; }
```

If you use an older C# / Visual Studio Version you can write something like this, and assign the field in the constructor or the field definition:

```
private readonly int property;
public int Property { get { return this.property; }}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep properties read only, you may just define their getter like this:

```
public MyProperty { get; }
```

Comment: does this work for all C# versions or only for C#6+ ?

Comment: it will work for all later than 2.0

Answer (score 4):

A property without set considered as a read-only property in `C#`, you need not specify them with a Readonly keyword.

```
public class GreetingClass
{
    private string _HelloText = "some text"; 
    public string HelloText => _HelloText; 
}
```

Whereas in `VB` you have to specify: `Public ReadOnly Property HelloText() As String`

Comment: Can return value through private variable; see updates in the anser

Answer (score 0):

More or less, from C#6 it s possible using something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    string MyProp { get; }
    MyClass { MyProp = "Hallo Worls"; }
}
```

Before C#6 you can use a read-only backing-field instead:

```
class MyClass {
    private readonly string _myProp;
    string MyProp { get { return this._myProp; } }
    MyClass { this._myProp = "Hallo Worls"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had googled *readonly properties in C#*, you would have got **100*no_of_answers_here** correct results.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx clearly states, a property without `set` accessor is readonly. So it's logical to think that applying `readonly` keyword in addition would cause redundancy, nothing else.

Additionally until C# 6.0 you could not set the `readonly` property even withing the containing type (say, a `class`). In C# 6.0, you can at least do so as a part of initialization. Meaning this is possible in C# 6.0, `public int Prop { get; } = 10;` When you do so, a `readonly` backing field is automatically generated and set to the value you chose for property initialization.