# Best Object layout in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What's the best object layout in ASP.net or at least.. what are the advantages and disadvantages of either case:

```
    Public Class Dog
        Public Breed as String
        Public Type as String
        Etc....
```

OR the use of properties and keeping variables private

Somewhat of a debate among our team about it. Just wanted to hear thoughts.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166433/why-ever-use-fields-instead-of-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never expose fields directly.

Use properties with private backing fields. This allows you to change implementation and to encapsulate logic around getting/setting them.

See what the [Visual Basic Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx) have to say on this.

Also, [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c) the differences between fields and properties.